# How can I retrieve a list of directories under /srv/salt/projects in the /srv/salt/top.sls

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I'm trying to use a for loop like below in my /srv/salt/top.sls file.

```
   {%- set prjlist = salt['file.find']('/srv/salt/projects',type='d',mindepth=1,maxdepth=1,print='name') %}
   # {{ prjlist }}
   {%- for prj in prjlist %}
      'role:{{ prj }}_server':
        - match: pillar
        - projects.{{ prj }}.server
   {%- endfor %}
```

When I run "salt -l debug myhost state.apply test=True" doesn't match the expected role with the for block above.  However if I replace the prjlist assignment with the hardcoded list that find.file should be returning like with

```
{%- set prjlist = ['expected'] %}
```

then salt finds the role as expected ¯\_(⊙︿⊙)_/¯.

If I do a "salt-call -l debug state.show_highstate" and look at the rendered top.sls output, when using salt['file.find'] command the comment line is shown as

```
#[u'expected']
```

But if I use a hardcoded list the comments becomes

```
#['expected']
```

Besides that the rendered blocks look the same.

I'm using version 2018.3.0 (Oxygen).

Is there anything wrong with the salt['file.find'] line ?

Is there another, better way I should be using to get a list of the directories under /srv/salt/projects on the salt-master ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`cp.list_master_dirs`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.list_master_dirs) instead.

```
{% for path in salt['cp.list_master_dirs']() if salt['file.dirname'](path) == 'projects' %}
  {% set prj = salt['file.basename'](path) %}
  'role:{{ prj }}_server':
    - match: pillar
    - projects.{{ prj }}.server
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This approach worked, but I don't see why the `file.find` approach didn't work.

Comment: `file.find` finds files on the minions, while `cp.list_master_dirs` lists directories on the master. The salt projects folders you're looking for are on the master.